# Weird error in python regarding scoping

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 5
def foobar():
    print (x) #Prints global value of x, which is 5
    x = 1 #assigns local variable x to 1
foobar()
```

Instead, it throws a

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

What am I misunderstanding in the comments? Note, I understand if i do x=x+1, it'll throw error due to 'accessing value of local scope x beforei it's defined', but in this case I'm doing x=1, which does not require reading of existing value of x! This is NOT a duplicate question.

Comment: If you have complaints about the duplicate closure, please discuss it in the comments. Reposting your question with a *"This isn't a dupe"* addendum isn't productive.

Comment: The error is coming from `print(x)` which uses the value of `x` before it is defined, not `x = 1`. The `x = 1` makes the variable local to the function; therefore, it doesn't have a value when `print(x)` is executed.

Comment: "but in this case I'm doing x=1, which does not require reading of existing value of x!" But you're doing it **after `print(x)`**, which **does**. You would realize this by **reading the [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message**, which shows a stack trace, indicating the line where the problem occurs. This is absolutely a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change a global variables value in a function in python, you have to do

```
x = 5
def foobar():
    global x
    print (x) #Prints global value of x, which is 5
    x = 1 #assigns local variable x to 1
foobar()
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is the explanation for the error in my code?

Comment: @user1008636 The error you get is explained in the first answer to the first duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: The use of `global ...` is discouraged when used multiple times as it can be tricky to keep track and mange functions that are modifying global or local variables. Passing the variable as a parameter is preferred

Comment: @user1008636, just to give you a clear view on how this happens (https://i.imgur.com/xkF6PKA.png), when the interpreter knows there will be assignments to a variable all the lookups on that variable are done from the local scope (LOAD_FAST).